# Unable to install mesos on centos 6.5

Tags: mesos, mesosphere

I am trying to install mesos package according to https://open.mesosphere.com/getting-started/install/#slave-setup but, when  I run `yum install mesos`, transaction abort with error message:

```
Error unpacking rpm package mesos-1.0.1-2.0.93.centos65.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/lib/libmesos-1.0.1.so;57c7a348: cpio: read
Failed:
  mesos.x86_64 0:1.0.1-2.0.93.centos65
```

any pointers? or is the packaging of this particular version corrupted?

I tried `mesos.x86_64 0:1.0.0-2.0.89.centos65` which seems to be working.

Answer (score 0):

The current mesos 1.x.x RPM installers do not handle upgrades from mesos versions < 1.0 gracefully in CentOS 6.X. A yum update of mesos from 0.28 to 1.1.0 produces the following error:

```
Running Transaction
  Updating   : mesos-1.1.0-2.0.107.centos65.x86_64
Error unpacking rpm package mesos-1.1.0-2.0.107.centos65.x86_64
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /usr/include/mesos/slave: cpio: rename
```

The workaround is to run:

```
rm -rf /usr/include/mesos/slave
```

And then re-run yum update (or whatever RPM management command you are using to upgrade mesos).

Source: https://github.com/mesosphere/mesos-deb-packaging/issues/87

Answer (score -1):

[Updated:]  A new RPM which fixes this error, 1.0.1-2.0.96, has been generated and is available for download at https://open.mesosphere.com/downloads/mesos/.  (Thanks @js84)

Comment: I think I should have made this a comment rather than an answer, sorry about that.

Comment: I guess I am not able to comment.  Just trying to add extra info that may be helpful to others.  What would have been the best way to do that?

Comment: The package was just updated. I just tested http://repos.mesosphere.com/el/6/x86_64/RPMS/mesos-1.0.1-2.0.96.centos65.x86_64.rpm , which worked fine for me...